# identity constraint key matches more than one value within the scope of its selector

Tags: xml, xsd

I wrote an XML which contains multiple "page" elements. The Page includes two child elements "parse" & "action".
The "parse" element contains parameter & "action" element contains "func". I want to apply identity constrains on contents of "parameter" & "func".
As shown in following xml & its schema.

```
<test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">

<page>
    <parse>
        <parameter>request_id</parameter>
        <parameter>auth_key</parameter>        
    </parse>

    <action>
        <func>auth_key</func>        
    </action>
</page>

<page>
    <parse>
        <parameter>request_id</parameter>
        <parameter>config_1</parameter>                
    </parse>

    <action>
        <func>config_1</func>        
    </action>
</page>

</test>
```

Its XML schema is

```
<xs:element name="test">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="page" maxOccurs="32"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="page">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="parse"/>
            <xs:element ref="action"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>            

<xs:keyref name="arg_key_ref" refer="arg_key">
  <xs:selector xpath="action/func"/>
  <xs:field xpath="."/>
</xs:keyref>
<xs:key name="arg_key">
  <xs:selector xpath="parse"/>
  <xs:field xpath="parameter"/>
</xs:key>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="parse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="parameter" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="32"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="action">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="func" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</test>
```

The problem is I am getting `Field "./parameter" of identity constraint "arg_key" matches more than one value within the scope of its selector; fields must match unique values` Error.
Because **request_id** is appeared in both "page" elements. Is it possible to limit the selector scope within the page element only?

Thanks in advance,
Kishore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is already scoped to the page level, the problem is in the definition.

```
<xs:key name="arg_key">
  <xs:selector xpath="parse"/>
  <xs:field xpath="parameter"/>
</xs:key>
```

says that the `parse` elements within this `page` must be unique with respect to their `parameter` value. But `field` xpath expressions must match a *single* node relative to the `selector`, and in your case there's more than one `parameter` within each `parse` element.

Instead you need

```
<xs:key name="arg_key">
  <xs:selector xpath="parse/parameter"/>
  <xs:field xpath="."/>
</xs:key>
```

to require that all the `parameter` elements within this `page` are unique with respect to their own values.